# how can I make this faster (just want to learn Julia better)?

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, julia

I am writing a small MD (molecular dynamics) engine in Julia and I noticed that 67% of the time spent running the following Ewald summation function is spent in garbage collection. Besides algorithmic improvements, which can certainly be made here, what can I do to make it faster in terms of Julia tricks / good practices?

```
function getEwaldEnergy(top::Topology, xyz::Array{Float64})::Float64
    # cubic box only for now
    tolerance::Float64 = 1.0e-24
    tryUntil::Int64 = 4  # 5 box sizes gets it to five decimal places
    L::Float64 = top.box[1]
    rc::Float64 = L / 2.0

    α::Float64 = 3.5 / (top.box[1] / 2)
    σ::Float64 = 1 / (sqrt(2) * α)

    λ::Float64 = 1.0
    ns::Array{Int64} = getCombinations(-tryUntil, tryUntil, 3)

    # self-energy corrections
    selfEnergy::Float64 = 0.0
    for i::Int64 in 1:top.nAtoms
        selfEnergy += (1 / (sqrt(2 * pi) * σ)) * (top.charges[i] * top.charges[i])
    end

    # short-range energy
    shortRangeEnergy::Float64 = 0.0
    shortRangeEnergyBefore::Float64 = 0.0
    for l::Int64 in 1:size(ns)[1]
        shortRangeEnergyBefore = shortRangeEnergy
        for i in 1:top.nAtoms
            for j::Int64 in 1:top.nAtoms
                ci::Float64 = top.charges[i]
                cj::Float64 = top.charges[j]

                idx::Array{Array{Int64}} = top.bondIdx
                bonded::Bool = false

                # check if i/j pair is bonded
                for k::Int64 in 1:length(idx)
                    if (i == idx[k][1] && j == idx[k][2]) || (j == idx[k][1] && i == idx[k][2])
                        bonded = true
                        break
                    end
                end

                if bonded == false && !(i == j && ns[l, :] == [0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
                    r::Float64 = norm(xyz[i, :] - xyz[j, :] + L * ns[l, :])
                    if r < rc - λ
                        shortRangeEnergy += 0.5 * ((ci * cj) / r) * erfc(r / (sqrt(2) * σ))
                    elseif r < rc && r > rc - λ
                        # switching function turns on
                        shortRangeEnergy += 0.5 * ((ci * cj) * (rc - r)^2 * (-2 * rc + 2 * r + 3 * λ) * erfc(r / (sqrt(2) * σ))) / (2 * r * λ^3)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end


    # long-range energy
    longRangeEnergy::Float64 = 0.0
    longRangeEnergyBefore::Float64 = 0.0
    volume::Float64 = L^3
    ms = ns

    longRangeEnergyBefore = copy(longRangeEnergy)
    for l in 1:size(ms)[1]  # no k = [0, 0, 0]
        if ms[l, :] == [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
            continue
        end

        # define reciprocal space vectors
        kVector::Array{Float64} = (2 * pi) * (ms[l, :] / L)
        k::Float64 = norm(kVector)

        # check this equal 1 good
        # println(exp(-im * dot(kVector, L * [ms[l, 1], ms[l, 2], ms[l, 3]])))
        strucFactor::ComplexF64 = 0.0
        for i in 1:top.nAtoms
            strucFactor += top.charges[i] * exp(im * dot(kVector, xyz[i, :]))
        end

        longRangeEnergy += ((4 * pi) / (volume)) * ((exp(-σ^2 * k^2 / 2) / k^2) * (abs(strucFactor)^2))
    end


    # this roughly cancels out long range energy due to bonded interactions (Tuckerman pg. 663)
    bondEnergy::Float64 = 0.0
    idx = top.bondIdx
    for b::Int64 in 1:size(idx)[1]
        for i in 1:top.nAtoms
            for j in 1:top.nAtoms
                if ((idx[b][1] == i && idx[b][2] == j) || (idx[b][1] == j && idx[b][2] == i)) # && !(i in isdone)
                    # println("firing j: ", j)
                    ci::Float64 = top.charges[i]
                    cj::Float64 = top.charges[j]
                    # rx::Float64 = xyz[i, 1] - xyz[j, 1]
                    # ry::Float64 = xyz[i, 2] - xyz[j, 2]
                    # rz::Float64 = xyz[i, 3] - xyz[j, 3]
                    rij::Float64 = norm(xyz[i, :] - xyz[j, :])
                    bondEnergy += (ci * cj * erf(rij / (sqrt(2) * σ))) / rij
                end
            end
        end
    end

    ewaldEnergy = shortRangeEnergy + longRangeEnergy - selfEnergy - bondEnergy

    return ewaldEnergy
end
```

Comment: If you have working code that you're looking to optimize/improve, your question should be asked on [codereview.se] instead, as it was created for that purpose. This site is for questions related to problems that you're having with non-working code.

Comment: Didn't read properly (I am on mobile), but sure what you DON'T need to is to explicitly annotate the type of the variables. That's totaly useless. Do it only for struct members or (but for specifying multiple methods if needed, not for performances) for function arguments.

Comment: so there's no way type annotation makes code faster? the compiler is that smart / good at runtime inference?  i do it to keep track of things but can get rid of it if it's not julian...

Comment: What is the definition of the `Topology` struct? And typical inputs to run the code?

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely get rid of the type assertions. They don't help performance, and sometimes harms it (because you may force unneded conversions). But you also need to post self-contained code. I'm a bit suspicious of what is inside `top` because of this line: `idx::Array{Array{Int64}} = top.bondIdx`. `Array{}` without a dimension parameter is an abstract type, which is bad for performance.

Comment: There are some rare cases where type assertions can help the compiler with complicated type inference problems, or where there is no way for the compiler to possibly figure out the type. But those should be properly identified first. `tolerance::Float64 = 1.0e-24` makes no sense since there is nothing to figure out. `1.0e-24` is _literally_ a Float64 _literal_.